# Pycaret 3.3.0 compare_models() show zeros for all models AUC

Tags: machine-learning, auc, pycaret

During evaluation of the model using compare_model(). All AUCs are zero.

This output of Pycaret 3.3.0 is weird. what's the reason for that?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm2ZT.png

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug of `Pycaret`.

Downgrade to `pip install pycaret==3.2.0` and `pip install scikit-learn==1.2.2`

You can track the progress to solve this bug here: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/pull/3935

Comment: Thanks for the comment - tested and working for Pycaret 3.2.0
System:
    python: 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable: D:\Projects\churn_pycaret_320\venv\Scripts\python.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0

Python dependencies:
      sklearn: 1.2.2
          pip: 24.0
   setuptools: 69.1.1
        numpy: 1.25.2
        scipy: 1.10.1
       Cython: 3.0.9
       pandas: 1.5.3
   matplotlib: 3.6.0
       joblib: 1.3.2
threadpoolctl: 3.4.0